# Image relative to a base URL on Tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there a way to convert URLs on **TinyMCE** to relative urls based on a given **base_url**? I want to prevent any part of the website base_href to be saved in the database.

I've always used absolute URLs, but when I need to change the website address or path (it does happen), I need to replace all URLs in the database.
How could I configure TinyMCE in a way that images' urls are converted to a relative URL based on the path where the website is hosted?

Example:

- My site is hosted at **example.com/xyz**
- TinyMCE is at **example.com/xyz/admin**
- Images are located at **example.com/xyz/images**

How to get TinyMCE to remove the base_url **example.com/xyz** but still display images correctly on the editor?

How to get images saved as `<img src="images/dummy.png" />` so the page can always load them based on its **meta base href**?

The current config replaces **example.com/xyz/images/dummy.png** to **/xyz/images/dummy.png**, which still contains a part of the url.

**DOCUMENT_BASE_URL** is a variable loaded from the config file, containing the website base_href.

```
convert_urls: true,
relative_urls: false,
remove_script_host : true,
document_base_url: DOCUMENT_BASE_URL
```